# Organizing images in emacs

Tags: files, images, bookmarks, image-mode, image-dired

There is image-mode and image-dired, but if you want to do anything except sequential viewing, they become clunky quickly. And they are slow for good quality photographs.

I would like to be able to go through my collection, quickly deleting and potentially even tagging (EXIF or something) images, similar to digikam but in Emacs-Style.

Comment: it is a long way from digikam.el but https://melpa.org/#/exiftool might be useful

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to categorize/organize files, including image files.

One simple way is using directories/folders as categories. Aside from using symlinks or hard links, this is a tree or forest organization. And even with links it's pretty hardwired.

Another way is to *tag files*. Tags can typically be pretty arbitrary, so tags let you organize categories as sets - arbitrarily overlapping, nesting, whatever.

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [tag files](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TaggingFiles) without necessarily visiting them.
[Autofile](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks) bookmarks are named by their destination file name (nondirectory part). You can have multiple autofile bookmarks with the same name, to bookmark files with the same name but in different directories.

[Bookmark+ tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) can be arbitrary strings (including space chars, newline chars, whatever).  Tags can even be key-value pairs; that is, you can associate any Lisp value with the name of a tag.

You can *group* (organize) bookmarks (e.g. some tagged image autofiles) in several ways, besides by tag combinations. You can show listings of just some set of bookmarks; you can have multiple bookmark files, for different purposes, ...  And you can *bookmark* any such groupings, so you just jump to a bookmark to use a given group.

Comment: I already use directory structure, but this is insufficient. Are BookmarkPlus tags usable by other software? This is a requirement for tagging for me, I don't want tags to get lost in some application-specific format.

Comment: Bookmark+ tags are stored in bookmarks, as field `tags`. A bookmark file has a simple structure and is plain-text, so bookmarks and their fields, including field `tags` are available to any application or tool that can access a plain-text file. Each tag is just a string.

Comment: Yes, a directory structure is typically a tree (or a forest, with multiple roots/drives). With symlinks and hard links it can be a graph, but that's still limited. Tagging files and directories is much more flexible; it gives you multiple different "directory" structures, each of which can be a graph - any organization you like.